# Will statically-linked functions have the same pointer-values across runs on the same machine?

Tags: c, posix

I want to add a quick-launch feature to [my postscript interpreter](http://code.google.com/p/xpost) so it can bypass the long (-ish) initialization routines and start executing user programs straightaway. So I've designed all interpreter memory to be contained in memory-mapped files. All internal "pointers" into this memory are actually integer byte-offsets from the base-pointer to the start of the memory file. So, I think I've prepared for this in the design.

My concern is with the operator table which contains function pointers. I suppose C itself gives no guarantees in this area, but can I assume that function pointers to statically-linked functions will remain the same for separate runs of the same executable? Does this depend on the presence of virtual memory? Does POSIX address this?

With Cygwin, I appear to get the same pointer value each time. But, *testing can never demonstrate the absence of bugs*.

*Edit:* In my defense, efficiency wasn't the only goal here. Encapsulating the memory usage was a bigger goal (with quick-launch as the cheese). Encapsulating has also been tremendously helpful in debugging.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization could ruin your party I think.

Comment: @Mat It's scary that Wikipedia can make a program misbehave, indeed.

Comment: Ooo. Yes, that would do it. I'll be careful to keep this an option, and probably not the default.

Comment: I imagine it might be possible to work-around the ASLR by doing dirty tricks with the pointers. If it's the base of the executable that's randomized, then the ptr_diff_t between the *fp* and *main* might still be constant. maybe.

Comment: Sorry, but just mentioning working around security features for the sake of efficiency gives me the shivers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe. Don't rely on it.

As Mat commented, ASLR randomizes addresses. So when it's enabled, you won't get the same pointers.
Without it, you're likely to get the same pointers. But tiny changes in the environment (maybe a patch in a library you're using) will break this. So you'll have a very unreliable program.

Comment: Yeah. I see. It's a bummer, but perhaps not fatal. I could store the function pointers in a separate table and initialize that explicitly.

Comment: You should do it for all pointers, not only function pointers.

Comment: I'll quadruple-check, but I'm pretty sure they're the only ones in there. I've already wrestled with various functions needing to recalculate pointers after calls which might allocate (which might grow (and move) the memory). `vi *.[ch]` ... `/[^/]\*[^/]/` ... nnnnnnnn :n nnnnnnnn :n ... :)